# USB3.0 super speed device descriptor failure

Tags: usb, windows-10-universal, usb-descriptor

I am trying to emulate a device as USB3.0 super speed (our platform support USB3.0 hub). Below is the device descriptor I am using for device enumeration.

```
0x12,                           /* Descriptor size */
0x01,                           /* Device descriptor type (0x01) */
0x00,0x03,                      /* USB 3.0 */
0x00,                           /* Device class */
0x00,                           /* Device sub-class */
0x00,                           /* Device protocol */
0x09,                 /* Maxpacket size for EP0 : 2^9 = 512 bytes */
<VID>                      /* Vendor ID */
<PID>,                      /* Product ID */
0x00,0x00,                      /* Device release number */
0x01,                           /* Manufacture string index */
0x02,                           /* Product string index */
0x00,                           /* Serial number string index */
0x01                            /* Number of configurations */
```

I run the USB3HWAnalyzer tool to analyze the failure issue and below is the error trace.
13094733443.428871: (UsbHub3/176)
        Event Message:DescriptorValidationErrorDeviceInvalidBMaxPacketSize
        PortPath:  0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0

basically it fails due to  -- 
0x09,                 /* Maxpacket size for EP0 : 2^9 = 512 bytes */

which I am not getting why?
Any valid reason for this issue?

Tnx!